# How do I monitor bandwidth usage in Windows 7, including a URL breakdown?

Tags: windows-7, networking, bandwidth

I want to monitor bandwidth usage in Windows 7 with the following parameters:

- geared towards single-user scenarios
- gives a breakdown of per hour bandwidth utilization
- includes per-host (URL) statistics

For example, I want to know that, between 1 and 2pm, `google.com` consumed 30MB.

Most of the methods I have found are either geared towards a business environment or at the network device level - neither of which are an option at the moment.

Comment: This question is offtopic in its current form (it's considered [product recommendaton question](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)). Please edit it to be more like "How do I...", not "What tool should I use...".

Answer (score 1):

Force all your traffic through a proxy (-cache) and then analyze the logfiles of that proxy. One option for a proxy is http://www.squid-cache.org/ and you might find some analyzer-software for it over at http://www.squid-cache.org/Misc/log-analysis.html.

There are tons of proxy-software for Windows so you might want to toy around for a while.

You have to use a proxy because you need everything tunneling through one system to be able to monitor things. DNS-queries (to resolve hostnames for any given urls) are usually a separated thing from HTTP-queries (which fetch all the resources into your browser).

Answer (score 0):

try a software called

System Explorer v4.2.2
weblink: http://systemexplorer.net/

SystemExplorer is FREE for personal and commercial use.
Requires operating system Windows XP,Windows Vista,Windows 7 or Windows 8.

hope it helps you in someway.

:)

Comment: From what I could tell this is more of a real-time analysis tool, not a historical reporting tool. Looks nifty though.